# extract posts cover images(first media) in orchard database

Tags: orchardcms

I want to have a query that extract all informations about blog posts in Orchard-cms Database. and i found [this](http://sebastienros.com/understanding-orchard-s-database) reference so i created some query like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM dbo.default_Title_TitlePartRecord 
 inner join dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord on 
 dbo.default_Title_TitlePartRecord.ContentItemRecord_id=dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord.Id 
 inner join dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord on 
 dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord.ContentType_id= dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord.Id
 inner join dbo.default_Common_BodyPartRecord on 
 dbo.default_Common_BodyPartRecord.ContentItemRecord_id=dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord.Id
 INNER JOIN dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord AS civr on
 civr.ContentItemRecord_id = dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord.Id
```

but  still i couldnt find any way to access posts first media(post image or cover image) Address!
do you know how can i get the posts image address in orchard database?

i found picture names in  a table named `Orchard_MediaLibrary_MediaPartRecord` but there isnt any foreign key which connected to this table(maybe i didnt find it)

can any body help me ...is there any diagram for orchard database??!!

Comment: Why do you want to have the query? Do you need the data in your orchard application?

Comment: i want to get all post datas to show it in mobile app...(web service) @devqon

Answer (score 0):

i found it... there is no foreign key field to reference image of the post. but there is a field named DATA in version row of the content item which contains an xml string.
one of the xml Elements is `<image/>` and contains id of image in text value.

```
       SELECT distinct dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord.Id as postId ,
 L2.Title as PostTitle ,
 civr.Data --this is xml field !!!!!!!!!
 FROM  dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord 
 inner join dbo.default_Common_BodyPartRecord on 
 dbo.default_Common_BodyPartRecord.ContentItemRecord_id=dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord.Id

 INNER JOIN dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord AS civr on
 civr.ContentItemRecord_id = dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord.Id
 inner join  dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord on
 dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord.ContentType_Id=dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord.Id

CROSS APPLY(select top(1) Title from dbo.default_Title_TitlePartRecord where ContentItemRecord_id =dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord.Id)L2
 where  civr.Published=1 and dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord.ContentType_Id=9  and   civr.Latest=1 order by postId desc
```

Comment: You should never query the Orchard database in plain SQL. Instead, you should be using the APIs off of `ContentManager`, that know about tenants, table prefixes, composing parts into content items, versioning, localization, etc.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy actually this query is just for test ...i used same query in EF database first in my web service project ...

Comment: Ah ok. Carry on then 